# dispatch mouse out event when the mouse not out

Tags: actionscript-3, events, tooltip, mouseevent, mouseover

I created a tooltip class.
When the mouse over on MovieClip it enable and when it out it disable.
The movieclip containt some other movieclips.
My code is that:

```
to.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, showTip);
to.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hideTip);
to.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MoveTip);
```

and the functions is that:

```
private function showTip(evt: MouseEvent) {
        if (tip != null && !tip.visible) {
            tip.x = evt.stageX;
            tip.y = evt.stageY;
            tip.visible = true;
        }
    }

    private function hideTip(evt: MouseEvent) {
        if (tip != null && tip.visible) {
            tip.visible = false;
        }
    }

    private function MoveTip(evt: MouseEvent) {
        if (tip != null && tip.visible) {
            tip.x = evt.stageX;
            tip.y = evt.stageY;
        }

    }
```

Its work but sometimes the hideTip function and the showTip function enable in same time and the tip is flashing.

Comment: all answers are interesting but setting your tooltip to not receive mouse events is easier.

Comment: @BotMaster I'd say it's better, not easier, because a tooltip should not be interactive by design. But this is not always the case, there are "interactive" tooltips like upgrade menus for towers in a TD game, for example, so this solution is not always acceptable. For the case of just text in a tooltip this is enough.

Comment: Typically this is done that way: the tooltip doesn't receive mouseevent (no unexpected behavior), the hovered object implements a IReceiveToolTip interface (to validate that it does accept tooltips), that interface should also enforce the text it should display (implemented by receiving object), when tooltip shows up a timer triggers, if timer runs out and pointer is still on top of tooltip, tooltip receive mouseevent and accept user imputs. This is rather standard and proves to leave out unexpected behaviors.

Comment: @BotMaster I've got to read about that interface, I'm yet to develop my own tooltip bicycle, so this is a bit of needed data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your tooltip obscures the underlying `to` movieclip, thus effectively making Flash to think that mouse is out of the `to` MC, triggering the mouse out listener. A possible solution is shifting the `tip` off the mouse cursor instead of displaying it right on top of the mouse position.

```
const offsetX:Number=4;
const offsetY:Number=4; // experiment with these  
private function showTip(evt: MouseEvent) {
    if (tip != null && !tip.visible) {
        tip.x = evt.stageX+offsetX;
        tip.y = evt.stageY+offsetY;
        tip.visible = true;
    }
}

private function MoveTip(evt: MouseEvent) {
    if (tip != null && tip.visible) {
        tip.x = evt.stageX+offsetX;
        tip.y = evt.stageY+offsetY;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
to.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, showTip);
to.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, hideTip);
```

That avoids the problem of dispatching the event, if the mouse changes e.g. between a letter and a transparancy in an area or between children of the same tooltip-target, which should completely have one tooltip. Sry for my english. Hope, it helps. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

As @BotMaster and @Vesper suggested, the `tip` is displayed under the mouse, which causes the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT` to fire.

To prevent this, do:

```
tip.mouseEnabled = false;
tip.mouseChildren = false;
```

Comment: Ahem, I suggested that, and seemingly hit, but your approach to fix this behavior is a tad better than mine.

Comment: sorry @Vesper for not giving proper credit. I quickly skimmed over the answers and didn't notice any `enabled` code, thus assuming BotMaster's comment was the only one suggesting it.